# Cakephp 3 : How to get user password without hash in user edit from ?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Here I have used auth component.In user edit from,my user password like this image

[image]

But here I want to see the password without hash. And also want to edit here. Is it possible ?

I have tried simple cakephp edit method

```
public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            } 
        }
    }
```

And used simple password input field

```
echo $this->Form->input('password',['class'=>'form-control']);
```

How can I see this password in user edit form without hash ?

Comment: If admin have a power to see user password then what can I do here ? For example I am creating a application where maximum user age is grater then 50, And there have a common issue forget password. If they forget password they will call admin to know what was the password.

Comment: You give them a _new_ password. It is not possible to see the plaintext password because it's not stored (thank god) in plain text or a format that can be decrypted.

Comment: May you provide me a link, how to decrypted plain test password ? Sorry If this question is not good.

Comment: `how to decrypted plain test password` **Not possible**

Comment: ok, only reset password is the option.

Comment: Yes, that is the only option. Password hashing is a one-way street. It can only be hashed, not unhashed. This is obviously for security reasons. If your database were ever to be compromised by an unauthorized person, they don't get a list of all your users' passwords (which would be very bad).

Comment: Why you need user password without hash. Compare both hash if not equal then store the new password. display original password may breach or harm security.